# removing gallery zoom

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have a gallery with a shutter (lightbox) effect in which on hover a zoom overlay opens (with the full-size image). I use wordpress, jQuery, next-gen gallery, and featuredimagezoomer.js.

The problem with the script is that it doesn't remove the zoom image overlay when I mouseout. I tried the  empty(), and remove() methods in jQuery, but none worked well.

this is the script:

```
jQuery("img#shTopImg").live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {

  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
var imw = jQuery("img#shTopImg").width();
jQuery(this).delay(200).addimagezoom({
magnifiersize:[350, 350], zoomrange: [3, 8], rightoffset: - imw });
  } else {

// remove logic goes here

}

});
```

and this is the page where it is:
http://baksagaspar.com/MH-work/collections/jungle-under-construction-2

You can see when it opens an image in a lightbox, and you navigate to some other picture, it's zoom overlay still stays on the screen

Any help please how could I solve this problem??

Comment: Try to change "else" by "else if(event.type == 'mouseout'), but I think is'nt enought !?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't bind the mouseover/mouseout to activate the plugin because the plugin does it already.
Simply do something like this :

```
$("img#shTopImg").addimagezoom({
    magnifiersize:[350, 350],
    zommrange: [3, 8]
});
```

Comment: sorry, but this still doesn't solve the problem...
-Akarun: the triggering event is OK with simple els also, but what to trigger??
-LekisS: yes, but it needs to be triggered by something, like mouseover-mouseout

Comment: -Lekis: yes, but when I put it in doc.ready, the img#shTopImg still doesn't exist, it is generated by the Shutter script for overlay image. 
and the addimagezoom script itself uses display:none for hiding the zoom-image, which in this case is not appropriate, because of the dynamically loading content in the Gallery.

maybe it would be needed to modify the addimagezoom script itself for this functionality? ( from: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm )